# In SQL, how can I handle a relation that is of the form a->b AND b->a?

Tags: sql

I'm developing a project for my Database course, and the application has the functionality of adding friends. The way I'm approaching it is having a table, defined below:

```
CREATE TABLE Friend(
    friend_from VARCHAR(10),
    friend_to VARCHAR(10),
    PRIMARY KEY(friend_from, friend_to),
    FOREIGN KEY(friend_from) REFERENCES Users(username)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(friend_to) REFERENCES Users(username)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Let's say there's a User A who is friends with User B. Should I have them both in the table, i.e.

```
+-------------+-----------+
| friend_from | friend_to |
+-------------+-----------+
| A           | B         |
+-------------+-----------+
| B           | A         |
+-------------+-----------+
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: It depends on whether you want the relationship to be bidirectional (Facebook style) or unidirectional (twitter approach)

Comment: The relationship will be bidirectional

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the relationship is bidirectional, then there is no meaning to the direction of the relationship - you can store a single row for each relationship in the database table.

Comment: Might be worth adding a check constraint such that e.g. `friend_from < friend_to` and then you don't have to worry about whether the opposite row may/may not exist also.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You are correct, of course, but as long as we are on the subject, I would also add a unique constraint on both fields.